# Settings for BizTalk orchestration to turn on/off feature into production

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

Is there way to create setting into BizTalk orchestration so I can turn on/off some features into orchestration on production if necessary?

I know I can create SQL table and port and read this setting from database, but it seems like overkill to me, is there anything more simpler?

I'm using BizTalk 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using SSO as a config store is the most common way to achieve what you need.

Details: [SSO as a Configuration Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee251728(v=bts.10).aspx)

Comment: I agree, using SSO would be my way to go as well.

Answer (score 2):

BRE could be used as a configuration store. It's simpler than rolling your own solution.